# Using the JXMapkit in java

Tags: swing, dictionary

plz tell the codes and/or logic to use the JXMapkit. I am using the swingx-ws-1.0.jar package in eclipse IDE. If a better (newer) package is available plz post the download link. Im trying to add the JXMapkit onto a JPanel with the following code but i'm unsuccessful in that also:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMapKit;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       JXMapKit kit = new JXMapKit();
       JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel();
       parentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       parentPanel.add(kit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       frame.setContentPane(parentPanel);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

error lies in the following line:

```
parentPanel.add(kit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Post the error stack trace in question - that will help to quickly determine what is your problem exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in the following link:

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/swinglabs/swingx-ws/1.0/swingx-ws-1.0-sources.jar!/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXMapKit.java?format=ok

works perfectly.
It requires the following reference libraries:

- swingx-all-1.6.3.jar
- swingx-ws-1.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use this code,it will work

```
           JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       JXMapKit kit = new JXMapKit();
       kit.setDefaultProvider(JXMapKit.DefaultProviders.OpenStreetMaps);
       JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel();
       parentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       parentPanel.add(kit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       frame.setContentPane(parentPanel);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setVisible(true);
```